# Сайт WP с одним ядром и несколькими бд

Tags: wordpress

Появился теоретический вопрос. Можно ли для одного ядра WP (каталог с файлами) использовать несколько баз.

Например по адресу site.ru будет работать с базой site, а сайт по адресу blog.com будет иметь базу blog, но у этих сайтов будет одно ядро (те один каталог с файлами) (те на хостинге они будут "смотреть" в одну директорию) ?

И если да, то как реализовать?

Comment: Адреса "blog" быть не может. Объясни внятно чего ты хочешь и зачем. Отредактируй пост, а не в комментах.

Comment: Сделать можно (например определяя в конфиге `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` ), только это имеет кучу недостатков и в целом нафик не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

нельзя, но если очень хочется, то можно. Всёже лучше запустить [multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) в одной базе.

config.php это тоже php файл и в нем можно добавить IF`ов.

Comment: Только так работать не будет

Comment: @ck1e я тоже так думаю, но дал этот ответ специально в образовательных целях. может быть в коментарии напишут в 2х словах почему так не  прокатит или кто-то даст развернутый ответ

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы описали, это стандартный функционал [мультисайта](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/ustanovka-multisite-mu). Для каждого подсайта (site.ru, blog.com) свой полный набор таблиц. Да, они в одной базе, но по сути - это набор почти независимых баз данных.